# Where does the linear term in the dual of quadratic program go?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems, quadratic-programming

I am faced with a quadratic program like so:

$$
\min_x \,\,\, \frac{1}{2}x^TQx+c^Tx \\subject \,to \\x \ge 0
$$

$Q \in \mathbb{S}^{nxn}_{++}\, z,c \in \mathbb{R}^n\, A \in \mathbb{R}^{m x n} \, b \in \mathbb{R}^{m} $

and I want to find the Lagrangian dual for this problem.  So, of course I use the Lagrangian function:

$L(x,z)= \frac{1}{2}x^TQx + (c^T - z^T)x$

Now, the textbook that I am using is asking me to show that the Lagrangian dual is $$\max_{y\le c} -\frac{1}{2}y^TQ^{-1}y$$.

I am not understanding how the linear term drops out of the objective function when we go from the Lagrangian function, $L(x,z)$, to the Lagrangian dual problem $-\frac{1}{2}y^TQ^{-1}y$.

Where is the term $c^Tx$ in the Lagrangian dual problem?

Answer (score 3):

The dual function $g$ is defined by 
$$
g(z) = \inf_x \, L(x,z) = \inf_x \, \frac12 x^T Q x + (c-z)^T x.
$$
We can minimize $L(x,z)$ with respect to $x$ by setting the gradient of $L$ with respect to $x$ equal to $0$, which yields
\begin{align}
& Qx^\star + c - z = 0 \\
\iff & x^\star = Q^{-1}(z - c).
\end{align}
We find that
$$
g(z) = L(x^\star,z) = -\frac12 (z - c)^T Q^{-1}(z - c).
$$
Thus, the dual problem is
\begin{align}
\text{maximize} &\quad -\frac12 (z-c)^T Q^{-1} (z-c) \\
\text{subject to} &\quad z \geq 0.
\end{align}
Perhaps you got this far on your own. Now just make a change of variables $y = c-z$ to obtain the version of the dual problem given by the textbook.

Comment: I followed that, thanks @littleO !  Now, how did the constraints on $z$ appear in the dual problem?  ( I know they are correct, but I don't see how you were able to carry them forward from the Lagrangian function, into the dual problem ). thank you

Comment: It appeared since $z$ is the dual variable associated with the *inequality* constraint $-x \leq 0$. Dual variables associated with inequality constraints must be non-negative.

Comment: Ah, I see.  That's because of dual feasibility in the KKT conditions, right?